# The expectation of picking times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stopping-times

Suppose you randomly choose a number from $[0,1]$ repeatedly, and each number with equal probability to be chosen. Once the sum of the numbers picked is greater than 1, you stop. Calculate the expectation of the number of times you need to pick.

I do this by direct calculation:

Lemma. Suppose $a>0$. Let
$ S_n(a)=\left\{\left(x_1, ..., x_n\right):\displaystyle0\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\leq a, x_i \geq 0, i = 1, 2, ..., n\right\}$,
$\mu\left(S_n(a)\right)$ denotes the volume of $S_n(a)$
, then
$\mu\left(S_n(a)\right) =\frac{a^n}{n!}.$

Proof. Let $x_i=ay_i$, we have:
$\left|\frac{\partial(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial(y_1,...,y_n)}\right|=a^n.$
Thus,
$\mu(S_n(a)) = \int_{S_n(a)} \mathrm{d}\mu=a^n\int_{S_n(1)} \mathrm{d}\mu=a^n\mu(S_n(1)).$
We only need to calculate $\mu(S_n(1))$:
\begin{align*}
\mu(S_n(1)) &= \int_{S_n(1)} \mathrm{d}\mu\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}x_n\int_{S_{n-1}(1-x_n)} \mathrm{d}x_1...\mathrm{d}x_{n-1} \\
&=\mu(S_{n-1}(1))\int_{0}^{1} (1-x_n)^{n-1} \mathrm{d}x_n\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\mu(S_{n-1}(1)) \\
&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\mu(S_{n-2}(1))\\
&=...\\
&=\frac{1}{n!}\mu(S_{1}(1))\\
&=\frac{1}{n!}    
\end{align*}
Thus
$ \mu\left(S_n(a)\right) = a^n\mu(S_n(1))=\frac{a^n}{n!}.$

Suppose at $i$th pick you get $X_i$, $X_i\sim U[0,1]$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,...\}$ and are independent. Assume at $\tau \mathrm {th}$ pick you stop, then:
\begin{align*}
P(\tau=n)&=
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i<1 \land \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\geq 1\right)\\
&=P\left(\neg \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\geq1 \land \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\geq 1\right)\\
&=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\geq1\right) - P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\geq 1\right)\\
&=\left[1-\frac{1}{n!}\right]-\left[1-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}
\end{align*}

Thus:
$E[\tau]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \left[ \frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!} \right]=e$

But later I'm thinking of using stochastic process to solve this problem. In stochastic calculus we can use Feynman-Kac Theorem to get a pde, and by solving the pde we can get the expectation. So I tried to let $Y_n=X_1+...+X_n$, let $u(n,Y_n)=E[\tau|Y_n]$, then $u(n,Y_n)$ is a martingale. And obviously, $u(n,Y_n)-n$ has nothing to do with $n$ now. But I don't know what to do next since I cannot use Ito formula now. It's a discrete case. Is it possible to solve this problem using some more advanced technique? Like theorems about stopping time or something like that.

Comment: Sorry but... **what for?**

Comment: Or, you might be thinking of computing the mean time $t(x)$ to exceed level $x$, for every $x>0$, by solving $$t(x)=1+\int_0^xt(x-y)dP_X(y)$$ which, when $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, readily yields $$t(x)=e^x$$ for every $x$ in $(0,1]$, and in particular the desired value $$t(1)=e$$  Doing so, indeed one embeds the time to exceed $1$ in a wider process but there is no stochastic calculus involved.

Comment: @Did So $P_{X} (y)$ stands for the cdf of $X$ right? And the formula of $t(x)$ is also correct for $x>1$ I guess? Thank you for solving my question! When I did problem like: suppose $X_t$ satisfies some SDE with standard Brownian motion, and $X_t$ starts from some point in $(a,b)$, and ask the expectation of the exiting time. We can set $u(t, X_t)=E[\tau|X_t]$ and use Feynman-Kac formula to get a pde of $u$. I am interested in whether we can use this in this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Did And I also tried to use optimal stopping theorem. I tried that $M(n)=\left[Y(n)-\frac{1}{2}\right]^2-\frac{n}{12}$ is a martingale, where $Y(n)$ is the sum of $X_1$ to $X_n$. Can we use optimal stopping theorem to get some conclusion here? Thanks a lot!